# Why use the reader macro #'?

Tags: clojure

I really don't understand what is this macro.

```
(def n 12)
=> #'lambda.core-test/n
#'n
=> #'lambda.core-test/n
(= #'n n)
=> false
(= #'n #'n)
=> true
(= 12 #'n)
=> false
```

I read somewhere that `#'x` is the same as `(var x)` so

```
(var n)
=> #'lambda.core-test/n
(var-get (var n))
=> 12
```

People seems to use it when reevaluation the definition of symbol doesn't work in REPL.

What exactly does this macro and how does it relates to reevaluation ?

Comment: Yes `#'x` is expanded to `(var x)`, which evaluates to the var itself instead of its value.

Comment: In which concrete case would I rather use a var instead of its value ?

Comment: If `x` has metadata then you can retrieve it with `(meta #'x)`. `alter-var-root` also takes the var e.g. `(alter-var-root #'n inc)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#'x` is just shorthand for `(var x)`

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/var

http://clojure.org/special_forms

The reason you would use either of these, is when you want to refer to the variable itself rather than the value stored within the variable. For example, you may want to write a doc generator that pulls the docstrings, arglists and other meta info from a set of vars. To do this you could use:

```
(def some-var "With a docstring" 1)
(meta (var some-var)) ;; or
(meta #'some-var)
```

I most frequently use this reader macro in conjunction with Stuart Sierra's component library. https://github.com/stuartsierra/component

For example, after defining a new system (using the component lib), I often need to do some stateful mutation to the defined system to start or stop it. Instead of referring to the immutable value as defined in var x, acting upon it, and then returning a new immutable value y, I want to update the value of var x in place, changing the actual var x itself. Here's a code example.

```
(require 'com.stuartsierra.component)
(def x (new-system))
(alter-var-root #'x com.stuartsierra.component/start)
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/alter-var-root

FWIW most clojure devs won't touch this reader macro in their day to day work, but definitely worth having a grasp on. Hopefully that helps!